# Return a method with variable list of arguments as reference in PHP

Tags: php, reference, php-5.3

I'm trying to return a value from a method as a reference in PHP5.3. I may be going at this the completely wrong way, but I am bringing an older project up to speed with some of the newer 5.3+ features.

Below is an example I whipped up to explain what is happening:

```
class Foo
{
    static $foobar = 5;

    function &bar()
    {
        return self::$foobar;
    }
}
// Doesn't work
//$test1 = &call_user_func_array(array("Foo","bar"),array());

// Doesn't work
//$test1 = &call_user_func_array("Foo::bar",array());

// Doesn't work
//$f = new Foo; $test1 = &call_user_func_array(array($f,"bar"),array());

// WORKS
//$test1 = &Foo::bar();

//Doesn't work
//$function = "Foo::bar";
//$test1 = &$function();

// WORKS
$f = new Foo; $test1 = &$f->bar();

$test2 = Foo::bar();

var_dump($test1);
var_dump($test2);

$test1 = 10;
echo "----------<br />";

var_dump($test1);
var_dump($test2);
var_dump(Foo::bar()); //returns 10 when working, 5 when not working
```

The very last `Foo::bar()` should return a 10, since `$test1` should be a reference to `Foo::$foobar` when everything works.

I realize that this example also uses some funky legacy PHP calling `Foo::bar` and the method `bar()` not being specified as static, but still being able to be invoked via  `::`

Any help would be greatly appreciated as the only fix I have so far is to just setup a `switch` on the argument list, and call the method directly based upon how many arguments exist.

Comment: Shouldn't Foo::bar() return the reference instead of referencing the result? I think $test1 is now a reference to a copy of Foo::$foobar ?

Comment: @PtPazuzu since you can't return a reference, something like `$result = &self::$foobar; return $result;` doesn't seem to change anything. using the code above with a working $test1 assignment, even doing `var_dump(Foo::$foobar);` will still return 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is just assigning $test1 to the value of $foobar (which is 5)

```
$test1 = &$f->bar();
```

This is just overwriting the value contained in $test1 with 10

```
$test1 = 10;
```

If you want to update the value within Foo, use

```
$f->foobar = 10;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was to return a reference, not to just bypass it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it already work in PHP 5.2.5: http://codepad.org/uMEIK210 (note the 10 as final result)?

I suppose, you would like to see the 10 three times.

For that (that `$test2` is also a reference to the class field) you need to specify the `&` on both sides:
`function &bar()` and `$test2 =& Foo::bar();`

See the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php):

> **Note:** Unlike parameter passing, here you have to use **&** in both places - to indicate that you want to return by reference, not a copy, and to indicate that reference binding, rather than usual assignment, should be done for $myValue.

So you just need to edit one line to get the (probably) desired 3 x 10:

```
$test2 =& Foo::bar();
```

### Final hint

[Do not use PHP references](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try declaring the function static. Also the call should be a normal call. prefixed by ampersand as already answered.

```
class Foo
{
    static $foobar = 5;

    public static function &bar()
    {
        return self::$foobar;
    }
}
```

The call:

```
$test1 =& Foo::bar();
```

Also, I can't see a valid reason for referencing a static variable. A static variable is a variable that doesn't change value between calls. It basically is a "global" var enclosed in a namespace. You only need read access from outside the class, the write should be done internally, as per the encapsulation principle. No need for the reference, really..